# Sorting and aligning the contents of a text file in Python

Tags: python

In my program I have a text file that I read from and write to. However, I would like to display the contents of the text file in an aligned and sorted manner. The contents currently read:

```
Emily, 6
Sarah, 4
Jess, 7
```

This is my code where the text file in read and printed:

```
elif userCommand == 'V':
    print "High Scores:"
    scoresFile = open("scores1.txt", 'r')
    scores = scoresFile.read().split("\n")
    for score in scores:
        print score
    scoresFile.close()
```

Would I have to convert this information into lists in order to be able to do this? If so, how do I go about doing this?

When writing to the file, I have added a '\n' character to the end, as each record should be printed on a new line.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not seeing it. Provide sample input and output.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) module, and then could use `sorted` to sort.

Let's says, scores1.txt have following

```
Richard,100
Michael,200
Ricky,150
Chaung,100
```

Test

```
import csv

reader=csv.reader(open("scores1.txt"),dialect='excel')
items=sorted(reader)
for x in items:
    print x[0],x[1]

...
Emily  6
Jess  7
Sarah  4
```

Comment: I have added my code above where the contents of the text file is read and printed. Would you be able to give me more information on how to use the csv module and what it does?

Comment: @Emily, added some test codes, let me know if you still have some problems

Comment: I am still having problems, I'm sorry. I couldn't get this to work. Each record has to be printed on a new line aswell.

Comment: @Emily, what does your scores1.txt looks like? could you post some part of it?

Comment: @Emily, to print that, you just need to loop it

Comment: Does it all go inside a for loop? And just to increase my understanding, what does the dialect='excel' section do?

Comment: Its meant for Excel-Generated CSV file, the very basic of CSV format.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like nobody's answered the "aligned" part of your request.  Also, it's not clear whether you want the results sorted alphabetically by name, or rather by score.  In the first case, alphabetical order (assuming Python 2.6):

```
with open("scores1.txt", 'r') as scoresFile:
  names_scores = [[x.strip() for x in l.split(',', 1)] for l in scoresFile]
# compute column widths
name_width = max(len(name) for name, score in names_scores)
score_width = max(len(score) for name, score in names_scores)
# sort and print
names_scores.sort()
for name, score in names_scores:
  print "%*s %*s" % (name_width, name, score_width, score)
```

If you want descending order by score, just change the `names_scores.sort()` line to two:

```
def getscore_int(name_score): return int(name_score[1])
names_scores.sort(key=getscore_int, reverse=True)
```

Comment: @Alex, maybe there is a typo? the line starts with "name_width = " and the line starts with "score_width = " should ends with a ")", not a "]"

Comment: @sunqiang -- you're right, tx for spotting this.  Editing to fix.

Comment: what about ascending order by score?

Comment: Is it possible to get ascending order without defining functions?

Comment: @Emily, ascending vs descending depends only on whether you add `reverse=True` to the call or not.  Extracting the score **as an `int`** for sorting purposes (so that 2 sorts before 11, etc) does require a function, though you can leave it unnamed (with a `lambda`) if you insist (makes your code less clear).  Or, you can instead use a loop of `namescore[1]=int(namescore[1])` then `operator.itemgetter` (also a lot less clear IMNSHO).

Answer (score 0):

1. to sort stuff in Python, you can use  [sort()/sorted()](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting).
2. to print, you can use print with format specifiers, str.rjust/str.ljust, pprint etc